# Как правильно объеденить таблицы

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы, картинок и статей. Нужно сделать вывод статьи с ее картинкой. Понимаю что нужно использовать join, но как именно это сделать нет понимания. Плюс ко всему нужно эту объединуню таблицу выводить посредством php

---

структура таблицы статей(articles) - id, short_description, description, name
структура таблицы картинок - id, image_name, ref(ссылка на статью по id(articles.id)), image_type

Answer (score 0):

Частичный ответ:

```
SELECT a.id article_id
     , a.short_description
     , a.description
     , img.image_name
     , img.image_type
  FROM articles a
  JOIN images img ON img.ref = a.id
```

По выводу запроса - посмотрите этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15450327/display-query-result-in-a-table/15450377